# How do I identify inputs that Chrome considers 'credit-card inputs'?

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, https, secure-context

I see the following warning for a page:

> This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar.

How do I identify the input that is causing this warning? There are no password inputs on the page, or anything that I can identify as a 'credit-card input'.

Comment: Are you using https for the page?   To ensure that the Not Secure warning is not displayed for your pages, you must ensure that all forms containing <input type=password> elements and any inputs detected as credit card fields are present only on secure origins. This means that the top-level page must be HTTPS and, if the input is in an iframe, that iframe must also be served over HTTPS.

Comment: No, http. My problem is the opposite of what you're suggesting: It's an http page, but it *doesn't* have any password or credit-card fields on it.

Comment: Do you have any extension which could be adding a password field usually inside a login form? Or any script?

Comment: One avenue to explore is form_structure.cc and autofill_type.cc. https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=return+HTML_TYPE_CREDIT_CARD_&sq=package:chromium&type=cs